# Resizing root partition in LVM broke Grub

Tags: virtualbox, root, grub2, lvm

I'm using Debian Wheezy hosted on W7 in Virtualbox. I needed to enlarge root partition then added a new virtual disk to virtual machine. Doing the steps mentioned below brings me to grub prompt. I:

- Added new virtual disk
- Formatted and mounted
- Created PV
- Added to same VG with root partition
- Extended root partition LV with `lvextend`
- Resized the file system.

Everything went well and I checked that with `df` command and `lvscan` but after reboot I couldn't boot the system. What point have I missed and how to recover the system?

Comment: Moderator, please add this to comments (I don't have enough rep to comment). Step 2 "Formatted and mounted" should not have been necessary. Update your post with the following information: What exact commands did you use for each step? What type of fs is the root filesystem? Can you share the output that you are seeing during bootup?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently having added a new disk to the LV of my root partition. After that grub couldn't find the root partition identified by UUID.
I edited the grub command line (at boot, by pressing "e") from `root=UUID=[blah]` to `root=/dev/mapper/[hostname]-root` (the LV containing /sbin/init).
This allowed me to boot. From there I updated grub's device map and grub itself:

```
> sudo grub-mkdevicemap 
> sudo update-grub
```